# meta tags and title doesn't show in google search

Tags: html, tags, meta

hey guys my meta tags like description and title doesnt show up on the search results when i search for my website on google, it shows an old title that i had placed  but when i click the link, it enters the site and the title changes to the one ive set in the code, here´s my code , is there anything missing.

```
<head><title>Angência de Marketing Digital em Angola: Imbound e SEO </title>
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name=viewport>
<meta name=description content="somos agência de marketing digital em Angola">

<meta name=keywords content="Marketing Digital,Marketing Digital em Angola,Marketing Digital google"> </head>
```

Comment: please clarify with more examples.. I do not understand.. search results meaning what ?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri when i search for my site online it doesnt show the correct title , it shows an old title , but when i click on the link it enters the site and  shows the updated title

Comment: Sounds like there is an error in your hosting service. Double check that the correct FILE is being loaded by your hosting service. Try updating it ... let me know

Comment: @JulianSilvestri yea i did that, i even downloaded the page i uploaded and its exactly the same! but i think there mite be something wrong with my server, maybe it takes a while to update! or something...

Comment: Yes it could take some time to properly update.. If you use developer tools on your site do you see the correct title?

Comment: @JulianSilvestri yeaa!! i do!!!

Comment: Google doesn't normally show any tags in it's results. Sometimes it does but it's added to the end of the title and thus if the title is long it's not seen.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming that there is not more than ONE title tag in your code. 
There are several reasons this could be happening:

1. Your source code is wrong - make sure your code contains exactly one title meta tag
2. Google cache is outdated - If you type in Google 'cache:' followed by the url of your site or page youll see what google has cached for your site. It the appeared date is before you made the changes you will have to wait for goolge to crawl your site again.
3. Google doesnt like your titles -https://yoast.com/google-page-title/
4. You have done nothing wrong and it could be your hosting service that is delaying the proper file to be uploaded and updated live.

Comment: This is totally incorrect, google never shows any tags in it's results unless you include it in your actual question title.